# Python Restplus - configure @api.route to accept / and /<query> methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']

Tags: python, flask-restful

I try to build API path:

- '/' - GET (with query string) to list all items
- '/' - POST to create/Save
- '/< id >' - GET to get 1 particular record
- '/< id >' - PATCH to edit/update this paticular record
- '/< id >' - DELETE to Delete this paticular record

and below is the code:

```
@ns.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])
@api.response(404, 'not found.')
class MyClass(Resource):
    @api.doc('Registration', responses={
        200: 'OK'
    })
    def get(self):
        """ Code Here """
        return results

    def post(self):
        """ Code Here """
        return results
```

above code is working fine for '/' GET and POST

but when it try to hit '/id' it throw me 404 not found

i tried to make `@ns.route('/< id >', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` but it doesn't work as well

how to design the code so it can accommodate my objective above?

Comment: What happens when you use `@ns.route('/{id}', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`?

Comment: hmm, nothing happen, how do i catch {id}? `def get(self, id=None)`?

Comment: Yes. Do you get an empty page or something?

Comment: no, it doesn't work, it will make my api accept: `GET /api/%7Bid%7D`